# Asp.Net Bootstrap reformat table for mobile media query without side scroll

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor, bootstrap-4, html-table

I found this code here https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/ but for some reason it doesn't work as expected for my table.
I'm working inside Razor view.

Here is my **table** code:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
            </th>

            <th>
                <a asp-action="Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["NameSortParm"]">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)</a>
            </th>

            <th>
                <a asp-action="Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["EmailSortParm"]">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)</a>
            </th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
                </td>

            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is **CSS** that I used:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
    background: #ccc;
    font-weight: bold;
}

td, th {
    padding: 6px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    text-align: left;
}

/*Media Query*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 760px), (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
{

    /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
        table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
        display: block;
        }

        tr {
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }

        td {
        /* Behave  like a "row" */
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 50%;
        }

        td:before {
        /* Now like a table header */
         position: absolute;
        /* Top/left values mimic padding */
         top: 6px;
         left: 6px;
         width: 45%;
         padding-right: 10px;
         white-space: nowrap;
        }

        /*Lable data*/
        td:nth-of-type(1):before {
            content: "FirstName";
        }
        td:nth-of-type(2):before {
            content: "LastName";
        }
        td:nth-of-type(3):before {
            content: "Email";
        }
}
```

Result **before** media query:

[image]

Result **after** media query is triggered:

[image]

I cut down repetition code just to make it easier to read.
Any ideas where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh never mind i guess i found the problem. position absolute is not needed:
[image]